# Android - How to send data from Activity Adapter to TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to send data from the adapter class to an Activity class that has `TabLayout`. But I am getting `NullPointerException`. I searched for some answers and I used one but it didn't work for me.

**Here is the Code**

**Adapter Class**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Player player = playerList.get(position);
    holder.playerName.setText(player.getPlayerName());
    Picasso.get().load(player.getProfilePhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_pic)
            .into(holder.playerImage);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlayerProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("playerId", player.getPlayerID());
            intent.putExtra("team", player.getPlaysFor());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

**Activity Class That has TabLayout**

```
public class PlayerProfile extends AppCompatActivity {


public String playerId, team;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_profile);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    playerId = intent.getStringExtra("playerId");
    team = intent.getStringExtra("team");

    ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new PlayerInfo(), "Player Info");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new CurrentStats(), "Current Stats");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new WholeIPL(), "Whole Stats");


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("playerId", playerId);
    bundle.putString("team", team);

    PlayerInfo info = new PlayerInfo();
    CurrentStats stats = new CurrentStats();
    WholeIPL ipl = new WholeIPL();

    info.setArguments(bundle);
    stats.setArguments(bundle);
    ipl.setArguments(bundle);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

static class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
    private ArrayList<String> titles;

    ViewPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        this.titles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        titles.add(title);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

**TabLayout Fragment**

```
    public class PlayerInfo extends Fragment {

String playerID, team;
TextView name, dob, batting, bowling, jersey;
CircleImageView circleImageView;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_info, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    assert bundle != null;
    playerID = bundle.getString("playerId");
    team = bundle.getString("team");

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: " + playerID);
}
```

It is showing null in the `Log` statement. So, Any suggestions on how can I pass the `playerId` to Fragment?

Comment: Please first check if the `player.getPlayerID()` is not null in your Adapter, then check it again in your `PlayerProfile` Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("playerId", playerId);
    bundle.putString("team", team);

    PlayerInfo info = new PlayerInfo();
    CurrentStats stats = new CurrentStats();
    WholeIPL ipl = new WholeIPL();

    info.setArguments(bundle);
    stats.setArguments(bundle);
    ipl.setArguments(bundle);

Above code is required for creating instances for fragment and setting value to them. 
You need to use these instances of fragment to the ViewPagerAdapter (As shown)

ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPageAdapter.addFragment(info, "Player Info");
viewPageAdapter.addFragment(stats, "Current Stats");
viewPageAdapter.addFragment(ipl, "Whole Stats");

**And then set the viewpageradapter** 

   viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

You're creating new instances of fragments and use setArguments on them and those instances are never used.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing new Fragments first, then defining new fragments and use setArguments on them and they're not used.
Specifically Look at these lines of code:

```java
    ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new PlayerInfo(), "Player Info");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new CurrentStats(), "Current Stats");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new WholeIPL(), "Whole Stats");
```

Here, you're passing new Fragments to addFragment and here:

```java
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("playerId", playerId);
    bundle.putString("team", team);

    PlayerInfo info = new PlayerInfo();
    CurrentStats stats = new CurrentStats();
    WholeIPL ipl = new WholeIPL();

    info.setArguments(bundle);
    stats.setArguments(bundle);
    ipl.setArguments(bundle);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

You're creating new instances of fragments and use setArguments on them and the new fragments never get used later.
Consider moving your adapter definition and addFragments below setArguments and use the defined fragments.